# Foursquare Web Search Suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, foursquare

Why my search suggestion keep returning '568 broadway' even after i change the authentication to my clientid and client_secret?

Running on:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/suggestCompletion?ll=40.7,-74&query=foursqu&oauth_token=
```

Tried:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3?client_id=
```

Returns only Clinton St

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the right query parameters for the query you are trying to make. The `&query=foursqu` part of the first URL means fetch venues that contains words that start with "foursqu". Similarly, your venues query contains the venue ID `40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3`, which is an instruction to fetch info only about the venue with that ID (Clinton St Bakery)